# How to configure the grpc client's source ip address and/or port?

Tags: grpc, grpc-c++

We are working on a `grpc` project and we are trying to identify a way to configure the IP that grpc client is using to connect to grpc server.

Our implementation in on c++ and we are using grpc v1.30. So far, we have observed that the default external interface is used and a random port is selected. Is it possible to configure the IP address and port of grpc client?

We are creating the grpc channel like this:

```
// target with grpc server's ip and port is of format "127.0.0.1:8080"

shared_ptr\<Channel\> channel = grpc::CreateChannel(target, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

gRPC C++ doesn't have a way to configure the IP address and port of the client.